# Проблема с загрузкой тайлов в libGDX

Tags: java, разработка-игр, libgdx

Пишу 2D platformer с помощью фреймворка `libGDX`.

Создал карту с помощью [Tile Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org/).
Загрузил ее в папку с проектом (так же добавил текстуры-блоки в формате **png**).
Но при компиляции приложение вылетает вот такая ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: res/maps/map.tmx
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:83)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:78)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:65)
at com.project.demo.GameMenuScene.<init>(GameMenuScene.java:118)
at com.project.demo.GameLoader.<init>(GameLoader.java:26)
at com.project.demo.ProjectDemo.create(ProjectDemo.java:45)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:147)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: res\maps\map.tmx (Internal)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.reader(FileHandle.java:163)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:81)
... 7 more
```

Прочитал в **google**, что нужно добавить в классе, который инплиментит  **ApplicationListener** (`implements ApplicationListener`), вот этот код (допустим, в методе `create()`):

```
public void create () {

    Texture.setEnforcePotImages(false); //!


    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new ProjectDemoInputProcessor()); //реализация управления клавиатурой
    sb = new SpriteBatch();
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false,F_WIDTH,F_HEIGHT);
    hudCam = new OrthographicCamera();
    hudCam.setToOrtho(false,F_WIDTH,F_HEIGHT);

    gameLoader = new GameLoader(this); //загружает игру

}
```

Но проблема в том, что метод `setEnforcePotImages(boolean b)` [удалили](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29398237/texture-setenforcepotimagesfalse-cannot-resolve-mothed-error-under-android-st).

Вот фрагменты кода, в котором создается и загружается карта:

```
class GameScene extends GameState{

//GameState нужен для того, чтобы загружать классы в качестве уровней
//Т.е я привожу все уровни к одному типу и потом загружаю их переопределенные методы для отрисовки конкретного уровня. 


GameScene(){
//создание карты:
 tileMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("res/maps/map.tmx");
 tmr = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tileMap);
 //code...   
}


 @Override
 public void render() {

    //фон
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //рисуем карту
    tmr.setView(cam);
    tmr.render();

    //физика
    b2dr.render(world,b2dCam.combined);

   }


 //code...

}
```

Вот строение папок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно сделать, чтобы приложение нормально компилировалось и карта загружалась?

Comment: а папка res/maps лежит в папке assets?

Comment: ApplicationListener здесь не причем

Comment: Нет, папка res/maps лежит в папке scr

Comment: ну тогда перемести папку или используй Gdx.files.classpath()

Comment: Можно подробнее про Gdx.files.classpath()? Где именно нужно это написать?

Comment: Подожди, в логах написано: File not found: res\maps\mlg.tmx (Internal), т.е. файл mlg.tmx, а в коде загрузки у тебя load("res/maps/map.tmx"), т.е. map.tmx. Как это понимать?

Comment: Я другие карты попробовал загрузить. Дело в том, что переписать кое-какие детали в вопросе я не успел. В том числе поменять путь, но дело было  все равно в настройке working directory. Именно в ней нужно было указать папку assets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта проблема решается следующим образом:

- Надо было проверить `Working directory` в проекте (В **IntelijIDEA** это `Run` > `Edit Configurations` > `Working directory: C:\Users\...` )
- Если в `Working directory` не указана папка `assets`, то изменить путь, который стоял ранее, на новый.

Было:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Все, что внутри папки `src` нужно загружать как classpath.Как сказанно в официальной документации по умолчанию метод `load()` загружает как internal, т.е. он пытается искать во внутренних ресурсах. Для андроида и вообще по умолчанию в libGDX проекте это папка `assets`. Если тебе все же нужно загружать через classpath, то попробуй данный способ:

```
GameScene(){
//создание карты:
tileMap  = new TmxMapLoader(new ClasspathFileHandleResolver()).load("res/maps/map.tmx");
 tmr = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tileMap);
 //code...   
}
```

P.S. Из документации:

> public TiledMap load(java.lang.String fileName)
>
> Loads the TiledMap from the given file. The file is resolved via the FileHandleResolver set in the constructor of this class. By default it will resolve to an internal file. The map will be loaded for a y-up coordinate system.
>
> Parameters:
>   fileName - the filename
>
> Returns:
>   the TiledMap

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/TmxMapLoader.html

Comment: Не работает. Попробовал переместить все в папку assets - тоже ноль эффекта

Comment: Вот мои папки: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kf6z8sgb7idoggs/%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%20%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2.png?dl=0

Comment: А так же вот я переместил папку res в assets: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o87ltbzvz4f0yk0/stack%20overflow%20problems.png?dl=0